# Customer Registration not working

Tags: magento2.3.5, customer-registration

I'm using Magento 2.3.5, the customer registration doesn't work. It won't upload a new customer to the admin side. I am using custom attributes for my registration but that doesn't seem like the problem because if try to edit my profile the changes are saved on the admin. So I'm not sure what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Of the custom customer attributes you have added, are any of them marked required and **NOT** visible on the customer registration page? If so, that could be the culprit. When the customer model gets saved, it will fail if there are attributes that are required that do not contain a value / fail the **required** validation.

I've had this happen with attributes I've created through extensions where they were initially created to be required but did not show up on the customer registration page.

Comment: Hi, the only attribute that is required but not visible is the store_id one. Is that causing the problem? I'm not able to edit this one since it doesn't appear to be a custom attribute.

Comment: I don't think store_id would be an issue if you haven't made any changes to that attribute and given that it is a built in attribute. Have you checked the magento logs? var/system.log, var/exception.log might give a clue as to why the customer model doesn't get saved.

Answer (score 0):

1. First check for form key in registration.php

I have added the form key code in the file after the  tag at line 21.

> app/design/frontend///Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

Code

```
<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
```

2. If the form key is already there, then it may be a browser issue (in my case it was working in all browsers except chrome). In that case
   if you are on localhost try to use 127.0.01 instead of localhost or your intranet IP in my case it was like(192.0.1.103/magento2)
3. If you are already on live site
   I think there is a problem with the session cookie with the chrome browser.

Comment: Yes, form key is there but it doesn't seem to be working on any browser.

Comment: You can try again by setting the default value for this field and then try again the steps you did.